# Weekend friday date in hive

Tags: date, hive

I have a date field column in hive, for which I have to calculate Friday's date of that week.what is the best way for achieving this. could you please help me on this.

Comment: what do you want to do for Saturday and Sunday..should it be previous friday or the next?

Answer (score 0):

You can subtract 5 (Friday's week day number) days from the week day of a given date, to truncate it to Friday of that week.

```
select date_add(your_date,cast(5-from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(your_date,'yyyy-MM-dd'),'u') as int))
```

Answer (score 0):

you can even try this if your field is date format , if not cast it to date.

```
select  case
when date_format('2018-07-30','E')='Sun' THEN DATE_ADD(cast('2018-07-30' as date),5)
when date_format('2018-07-30','E')='Mon' THEN DATE_ADD(cast('2018-07-30' as date),4)
when date_format('2018-07-30','E')='Tue' THEN DATE_ADD(cast('2018-07-30' as date),3)
when date_format('2018-07-30','E')='Wed' THEN DATE_ADD(cast('2018-07-30' as date),2)
when date_format('2018-07-30','E')='Thu' THEN DATE_ADD(cast('2018-07-30' as date),1)
when date_format('2018-07-30','E')='Fri' THEN '2018-07-30'
when date_format('2018-07-30','E')='Sat' THEN DATE_ADD(cast('2018-07-30' as date),-1)
end as a
```